# Sublime Text 2: How to search for every instance of an applied class?

Tags: html, css, search

I was wondering if anyone knows of a plugin or a native way to search for every instance of a class applied to an element in Sublime Text 2?

An example of what I am trying to achieve:

- I have 20 .jsp's and I want to find every element that has the class "sample".
- I can search for class="sample, but that will only return every instance where "sample" is the first defined class on the element.
- Is there a way to do something like "class=" + "sample" ?

I imagine this may be achievable using Regex, but that is way over my head. Any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the only way is a regex. you would be looking for something like this

```
/\sclass=['"][^'"]*\s+sample\s+[^'"]*['"]/
```

but this is not absolutely strict (because of the ambiguous quotes ' or ")